# PySerial | OS X to Raspberry migration USB Folder Name?

Tags: python, debian, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I use this line to start serial connection with my arduinos via OSX.

```
SER = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbmodem26431', 9600, timeout=1, parity='N', rtscts=1)
```

Now I want to run my python from my rasp, but I get:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/cu.usbmodem26431'
```

I'm used to this error cause at the beginning of my learnings I have struggled with that a lot. I know It's not the right folder. But I bought an USB HUB from amazon and the above address that I got on the OSX Arduino IDE app work like a charm. But I don't want to install it on the pi just to know the folder name once I'm not handling my controllers with it. I have googled and found the lsusb cmd.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2341:0043 Arduino SA Uno R3 (CDC ACM)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2341:0042 Arduino SA Mega 2560 R3 (CDC ACM)
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2341:0043 Arduino SA Uno R3 (CDC ACM)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2341:0042 Arduino SA Mega 2560 R3 (CDC ACM)
```

I have switched the uno USB port and the command show this as expected. But when I connect the Arduinos through my amazon usb hub I get.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2109:2811
```

How do I find out the exact folder name on both situation to put on the first line??
Its a headless pi. I use ssh. Do not know if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino create device /dev/ttyACMx

Run:

$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM*

This device /dev/ttyACM should be used in serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACMx', 9600, timeout=1, parity='N', rtscts=1)

Comment: Not on Debian Wheezy. Asked this question long time ago but forgot to answer it myself. As of right now, on the lastest stable version on the latest board.  I use this code       if platform.dist()[0] == "debian":     SER = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS99', 9600)

Comment: actually you are right. I just realized that I am using an arduino connected through the GPIO, so the folder is different. The thing is that I develop for the Rpi but I actually write the code on my Ubuntu or OSX.  To make my life easier I check which platform I am using and then open the correct port. So I can git push/pull without ever minding to set the right folder. How would udev help me?

Answer (score 0):

With udev you can create the device as: `/dev/arduino`
Based in major and minor number of the device.
    http://cleitonbueno.com/linux-o-poderoso-udev/